# Form Submit with playframework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Good Morning,
I have a Form and i want too submit it with two buttons each one of
them do the submit and redirect me to another page, How can i do that
with play Framework ??
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post the code you have? This question will likely be closed without additional information.

Answer (score 9):

in your template do

```
#{form @nameOfTheController.nameOfTheAction()}


... some stuff

<input type='submit' name='action1' value="Submit button 1" />
<input type='submit' name='action2' value="Submit button 2" />
#{/form}
```

and in your controller with the action

```
public static void nameOfTheAction(String action1, String action2)
{
  if(action1 != null)
  { 
   // do logic that should happen when button 1 is pressed
  } 
  else if (action2 != null)
  { 
   // do logic that should happen when button 2 is pressed
  } 

}
```